# Change .mdf local database and transfer to SQL Server 2014 with user sa .. later on I want to upload my project to hosting or iis host

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, hosting

I have faced issues after finish my ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework project.

I have changed the connection string and point to my SQL Server with user `sa` to generate the database.

I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot find the object "dbo.Comments" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.'

When I return to the local connection string, everything is working fine again.

Local connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
                           AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ElectronicHarajPro-20200323090456.mdf;
                           Initial Catalog=aspnet-ElectronicHarajPro-20200323090456;
                           Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

SQL Server connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
                           Server=MININT-3V9GJ88;
                           Database=ElectronicHarajPro;
                           User Id=sa;Password=123456;
                           Integrated Security=false" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server-based connection string contains **two** conflicting entries - one for `Data Source=` (pointing to the local SQL Server LocalDB instance), another for `server=` (which I *guess* is the SQL Server machine).

You need to ensure you use **only one** of those two!

Try this :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Server=MININT-3V9GJ88;Database=ElectronicHarajPro;
                           User Id=sa;Password=123456;Integrated Security=false" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your new connection string. We either use `DataSource` or `Server` property to specify the SQL server database instance in the connection string. I suggest you construct the connection string by using `SQL Server Object Explorer` in `Visual Studio`.
[image]
[image]
[image]
About the `Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider` for SQL Server connection string, please refer to the below documentation.
https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.